# Junit Test in java EE (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I'm creating a simple web application in JAVA EE using (EJB, JPA and JPQL).  I want to know how to test the model using mockito to test the EJB.  I want to mock the context (database, and properties)

How do I do that ?

```
@Mock
private EntityManager mockedEntityManager;
private static TendererBean tendererBean;
private static TendererManagerBean tendererManagerBean;   
private static EJBContainer container;
final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("jdbc/Mydatabase", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
    p.put("jdbc/Mydatabase.JdbcDriver", "apache_derby_net");
    p.put("jdbc/Mydatabase.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Mydatabase");
    container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
    final Context context = container.getContext();
    tendererBean = (TendererBean) context.lookup("java:global/classesTendererManagerBean");
```

Comment: I see you're trying to use derby, like that. Rather than ask "how do I do that", describe the problem you are having with your attempt.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that i want create test unit for my EJB methods like (register, update, and delete), for that i should mock my context, in my application i'm using JSF, EJB and JPA for persistence

Comment: Are you using CDI? Dependency injection makes testing/mocking a lot easier. If you don't use it then I would suggest looking into dependency injection first.

Answer (score 2):

> Alex is right, you should not need database connections in a unit test (unless you trying to create an integration test) You can try mocking them like this. The code may be messy, hope it helps

```
public class ChargeServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private ChargeService chargeService;

@Mock
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Mock
private Query query;
@Mock
private Biller biller;
@Mock
private Client client;

private String expectedSqlQuery1 = "Select count(c) from ClientContractCharge c where c.clientContract.biller =?1 and c.recurringInvoice = true and c.clientContract.client = ?2 and (c.dateCreated >= ?3 or c.dateLastUpdated >= ?3)  order by c.dateCreated ASC";

@Before
public void before() {
    chargeService = new ChargeService();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void listCountTest1() {
    when(entityManager.createQuery(expectedSqlQuery1)).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.getSingleResult()).thenReturn((long) 10);
    Long count = chargeService.listCount(biller, client);
    verify(query).setParameter(1, biller);
    assertEquals(count, Long.valueOf(10));
}
}
```

Service class

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean public class ChargeService {
public long listCount(Biller biller, Client client) {

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("Select count(c) from ClientContractCharge c where c.clientContract.biller =?1 and c.recurringInvoice = true ");
    if (client != null) {
        s.append("and c.clientContract.client = ?2 ");
    }
    s.append(" order by c.dateCreated ASC");
    Query q = em.createQuery(s.toString());
    q.setParameter(1, biller);
    if (client != null) {
        q.setParameter(2, client);
    }

    return (long) (Long) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to hassle around with db properties in your test code. Another thing to keep in mind: A *unit test* should not need a database connection, because then it's more than a unit test, it should mock away the persistence.

`EntityManager` can easily be mocked with for example Mockito. Additionally, you can mock a `Query` to get the needed result for the test.

Check out [Adam Bien's post on Mocking JPA EntityManager and Query](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/mocking_jpa_entitymanager_with_query) for how this can be done.